# Titanium Android Horizontal & Vertical Scroll

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

Titanium appcelerator while scrolling horizontally, ui is scrolling vertically. Is there anyway to lock vertical scrolling while horizontal scrolling ?

Answer (score 1):

**For horizontal scrolling:**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window backgroundColor="white">
        <ScrollView backgroundColor="gray" layout="horizontal" width="Ti.UI.FILL" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" scrollType="horizontal">
            <View left="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View left="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View left="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View left="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View left="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View left="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View left="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View left="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View left="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
        </ScrollView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**For vertical scrolling:**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window backgroundColor="white">
        <ScrollView backgroundColor="gray" layout="vertical" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" height="Ti.UI.FILL" scrollType="vertical">
            <View top="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View top="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View top="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View top="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View top="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View top="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View top="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View top="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
            <View top="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="red" />
        </ScrollView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**Titanium Classic Example**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white'
});

var scrollview = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    backgroundColor : "gray",
    layout : "horizontal",
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    scrollType : "horizontal"
});

for (var i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    scrollview.add(createView());
}

win.add(scrollview);

win.open();

function createView() {
    return Ti.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : 'red',
        width : 100,
        height : 100,
        left : 10
    });
}
```

***Your keypoint to restrict the scroll direction on Android is [scrollType](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView-property-scrollType) property.***

Comment: I am not using alloy. How can i fix this from javascript file ? I did not use alloy.

Comment: Just set the scrollType property to "horizontal" or "vertical" depending on your case like Prashant Saini said

Comment: Edited my answer with Classic code. But it's recommended that you better get used to Alloy asap before you start facing huge codes and hence large number of issues like syntax errors or other coding errors.